# How to get Data-Price for radio select - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Now i have this script and it work fine but when i try to select one radio + check checkbox i have only basic price + checkbox value i want basic price + radio + checkbox.
Can you help me? :)

```js
if (document.getElementById("getPrice")) {
  var basePrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("getPrice").value);
  $(".choice").click(function() {
    var newPrice = basePrice;
    newPrice += parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price'));
    newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
    $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
  });
}
```

```css
.choice {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="input" id="getPrice" value="899">

<div class="choice active" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" data-price="99" title="" data-original-title="+ 99 PLN">
<input type="radio" class="calculate" name="option1" value="House" checked="checked">
</div>

<div class="choice active" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" data-price="25" title="" data-original-title="+ 99 PLN">
<input type="radio" class="calculate" name="option1" value="House" checked="checked">
</div>

<div class="choice active" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox" rel="tooltip" data-price="122" title="" data-original-title="+ 99 PLN">
<input type="checkbox" class="calculate" name="option1" value="House" checked="checked">
</div>
<a id="item-price">899</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted isn't complete, I had to fill it by myself.
If you want yo use your custom attribute in element, use `attr='value'` pattern.

```js
if (document.getElementById("getPrice")) {
  var basePrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("getPrice").value);
  $(".choice").find('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    var newPrice = basePrice;
    if ($(".choice").find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
      newPrice = parseFloat($(this).parent().attr('data-price')) + parseInt($(".choice").find('input[type=checkbox]').parent().attr('data-price')) + basePrice;
      newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
      console.log(newPrice);
    } else {
      console.log(basePrice + parseFloat($(this).parent().attr('data-price')));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <input type="input" id="getPrice" value="899">

  <div class="choice active" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" data-price="99" title="" data-original-title="+ 99 PLN">
    <input type="radio" class="calculate" name="option1" value="House" checked="checked">
  </div>

  <div class="choice active" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" data-price="25" title="" data-original-title="+ 99 PLN">
    <input type="radio" class="calculate" name="option1" value="House" checked="checked">
  </div>

  <div class="choice active" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox" rel="tooltip" data-price="122" title="" data-original-title="+ 99 PLN">
    <input type="checkbox" class="calculate" name="option1" value="House" checked="checked">
  </div>
  <a id="item-price">899</a>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe because i have more class choice to select?

Comment: @MaciejWojtasik It's not about copying and pasting raw code into your code. You have to adjust it. You didn't share your whole code with us, I was unable to answer you precisely...

Comment: Yes, I know, but can you tell me where something changed?

Comment: Where you changed

Comment: Ohh shit i'am very stupid i do data-price:"99" must be data-price="99" ;;
Thanks you now it work

Comment: if i have another one choice, how can i sum it to all? when i click choice one radio and choice two checkbox i have only one sum

Comment: @MaciejWojtasik Specify your question.

Comment: @MaciejWojtasik You want to sum all?

Comment: i want sum one of radio + all checkbox

Comment: every time i see 1145.00 in test

Comment: @MaciejWojtasik Check again.

Comment: now is perfect, only this if i uncheck checkbox price is still there :(

Comment: you know how to do that?

Comment: @MaciejWojtasik Done.

Comment: nice but when i uncheck checkobx price from radio has been deleted

Comment: @MaciejWojtasik You have to trigger the change of radio box, to see the result.

Comment: and i cant to use
(".choice").find('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
because input is position absolute and left: 999999999 i see only the .choice :(

Comment: @MaciejWojtasik I would like to help you, but I can't :(

Comment: Okay, nothing will not happen :) I'm sorry I took you so much time, I can well program in laravel, but javascript has not yet learned. Can see a page on skype can think of something? Maybe we can use a "Next" button